# JavaScript code is not working as expected in browser

Tags: javascript, closures

I would like solve the function calling with pattern **add(n)(m)(o)......(nth)** and get the result of addition of n + m + o .... + nth

**Constraints: Please do not use global variable(total)**

Can I use approach 1 via Approach 2 ?

Approach 1: I tried like this: (Not working)

```
function CL(){
    var t = 0
    var add = n => { 
        this.total += n; 
        return add;
    }
    return {
        total: t, 
        add: add
    }
}
var res = CL();
res.add(2)(3)(4)(5) ....... (nth) ;
console.log(res.total); // 14 expected
```

Approach 2: I solve this using global variable(total) like:

```
var total = 0;
function add(n){
    total += n;
    return add;
}
add(2)(3)(4)(5);
console.log(total); // now correct 14
```

Comment: Not possible without a closing `()` or some other trickery.

Comment: You could do lazy evaluation, but then your invocation would be different: https://jsfiddle.net/Lo7zg6v2/